# python 3 logging traceback

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I get the following traceback

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 994, in emit
  stream.write(msg)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I don't recall adding anything to this script and it worked before. Here is the code related to logging

```
logFileMode = 'wb'  
logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/download.log',format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG, filemode = logFileMode)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  
logging.info('Script started')
```

Comment: Is `msg` a string or a bytes object?

Comment: I am assuming that what is in the logging.info() is the msg. If am correct then I would also assume it is a string. This same code works in another script

Comment: changing file mode to w works but I don't under stand why it doesn't work with wb.

Comment: If you're opening the log as `wb`, then any messages you log will be expected to be `bytes` objects, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting , i got the same problem with Logging module.
[SOLVED] by changing FileHandler MODE to 'a+' or 'w+' not 'ab' nor 'wb'.

```
from logging.handlers import WatchedFileHandler as Watch
import threading

self.commonLogFileName = gen_common_filename()
self.commonLogFileHandler = Watch(self.commonLogFileName, mode='a+')
self.commonLogFileHandler.setFormatter(self.format)
self.root.addHandler(self.commonLogFileHandler)
# Create new log record
self.root.log(level, dbgMsg)
```